# RapidXML - Code creates unexpected result

Tags: c++, recursion, rapidxml

I have the following XML

```xml
<ActionMaps version="1" optionsVersion="2" rebindVersion="2" profileName="full_export">
 <CustomisationUIHeader label="full_export" description="" image="">
  <devices>
   <keyboard instance="1"/>
   <mouse instance="1"/>
  </devices>
  <categories>
   <category label="@ui_CCSpaceFlight"/>
   <category label="@ui_CGLightControllerDesc"/>
   <category label="@ui_CCFPS"/>
   <category label="@ui_CCEVA"/>
   <category label="@ui_CGOpticalTracking"/>
   <category label="@ui_CGInteraction"/>
  </categories>
 </CustomisationUIHeader>
 <options type="keyboard" instance="1" Product="Tastatur {6F1D2B61-D5A0-11CF-BFC7-444553540000}">
  <flight_move_yaw exponent="1.5"/>
 </options>
 <modifiers />
 <actionmap name="spaceship_general">
  <action name="v_close_all_doors">
   <rebind input="kb1_0"/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_cooler_throttle_down">
   <rebind input="kb1_6"/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_cooler_throttle_up">
   <rebind input="kb1_5"/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_eject">
   <rebind input="kb1_1"/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_emergency_exit">
   <rebind input="kb1_4"/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_exit">
   <rebind input="kb1_2"/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_flightready">
   <rebind input="kb1_7"/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_lock_all_doors">
   <rebind input="kb1_equals"/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_open_all_doors">
   <rebind input="kb1_9"/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_self_destruct">
   <rebind input="kb1_3"/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_toggle_all_doorlocks">
   <rebind input="kb1_minus"/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_toggle_all_doors">
   <rebind input="kb1_8"/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_unlock_all_doors">
   <rebind input="kb1_q"/>
  </action>
 </actionmap>
 <actionmap name="spaceship_view">
  <action name="v_view_cycle_fwd">
   <rebind input="kb1_u"/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_view_dynamic_focus_in">
   <rebind input="kb1_rbracket"/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_view_dynamic_focus_out">
   <rebind input="kb1_a"/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_view_freelook_mode">
   <rebind input="kb1_lbracket"/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_view_look_behind">
   <rebind input="kb1_s"/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_view_mode">
   <rebind input="kb1_i"/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_view_pitch_down">
   <rebind input="kb1_t"/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_view_pitch_mouse">
   <rebind input="mo1_ "/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_view_pitch_up">
   <rebind input="kb1_r"/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_view_yaw_left">
   <rebind input="kb1_w"/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_view_yaw_mouse">
   <rebind input="mo1_ "/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_view_yaw_right">
   <rebind input="kb1_e"/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_view_zoom_in">
   <rebind defaultInput="mwheel_up" input="kb1_o"/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_view_zoom_out">
   <rebind defaultInput="mwheel_down" input="kb1_p"/>
  </action>
 </actionmap>
 <actionmap name="spaceship_movement">
  <action name="v_accel_range_down">
   <rebind input="kb1_v"/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_accel_range_up">
   <rebind input="kb1_c"/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_afterburner">
   <rebind input="kb1_down"/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_autoland">
   <rebind input="kb1_pgup"/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_brake">
   <rebind input="kb1_backslash"/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_ifcs_toggle_cruise_control">
   <rebind input="kb1_left"/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_ifcs_toggle_esp">
   <rebind input="kb1_rctrl"/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_ifcs_toggle_gforce_safety">
   <rebind input="kb1_ralt"/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_ifcs_toggle_speed_limiter">
   <rebind input="kb1_lalt"/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_ifcs_toggle_vector_decoupling">
   <rebind input="kb1_b"/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_pitch_down">
   <rebind input="kb1_f"/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_pitch_up">
   <rebind input="kb1_d"/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_roll_left">
   <rebind input="kb1_k"/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_roll_right">
   <rebind input="kb1_l"/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_speed_range_down">
   <rebind input="kb1_x"/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_speed_range_up">
   <rebind input="kb1_z"/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_strafe_back">
   <rebind input="kb1_rshift"/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_strafe_down">
   <rebind input="kb1_m"/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_strafe_forward">
   <rebind input="kb1_slash"/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_strafe_left">
   <rebind input="kb1_comma"/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_strafe_longitudinal_invert">
   <rebind input="kb1_lctrl"/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_strafe_right">
   <rebind input="kb1_period"/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_strafe_up">
   <rebind input="kb1_n"/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_target_match_vel">
   <rebind input="kb1_apostrophe"/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_toggle_landing_system">
   <rebind input="kb1_up"/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_toggle_qdrive_engagement">
   <rebind input="kb1_insert"/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_toggle_qdrive_spooling">
   <rebind input="kb1_pgdn"/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_toggle_relative_mouse_mode">
   <rebind input="kb1_j"/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_toggle_vtol">
   <rebind input="kb1_right"/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_toggle_yaw_roll_swap">
   <rebind input="kb1_semicolon"/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_yaw_left">
   <rebind input="kb1_g"/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_yaw_right">
   <rebind input="kb1_h"/>
  </action>
 </actionmap>
 <actionmap name="spaceship_targeting">
  <action name="v_aim_pitch_down">
   <rebind input="kb1_print"/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_aim_pitch_up">
   <rebind input="kb1_home"/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_aim_yaw_left">
   <rebind input="kb1_delete"/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_aim_yaw_right">
   <rebind input="kb1_end"/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_enter_remote_turret_1">
   <rebind input="kb1_lshift+1"/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_enter_remote_turret_2">
   <rebind input="kb1_lshift+2"/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_enter_remote_turret_3">
   <rebind input="kb1_lshift+3"/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_invoke_ping">
   <rebind defaultInput="mouse2" input="kb1_np_enter"/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_look_ahead_enable">
   <rebind input="kb1_scrolllock"/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_look_ahead_start_target_tracking">
   <rebind input="kb1_pause"/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_target_cycle_all_back">
   <rebind input="kb1_np_7"/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_target_cycle_all_fwd">
   <rebind input="kb1_np_subtract"/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_target_cycle_friendly_fwd">
   <rebind input="kb1_np_8"/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_target_cycle_hostile_back">
   <rebind input="kb1_np_6"/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_target_cycle_hostile_fwd">
   <rebind input="kb1_np_5"/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_target_cycle_pinned_back">
   <rebind input="kb1_np_4"/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_target_cycle_pinned_fwd">
   <rebind input="kb1_np_add"/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_target_cycle_reticle_mode">
   <rebind input="kb1_np_period"/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_target_cycle_subitem_back">
   <rebind input="kb1_np_3"/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_target_cycle_subitem_fwd">
   <rebind input="kb1_np_2"/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_target_deselect_entity">
   <rebind input="kb1_np_multiply"/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_target_focus_root_entity">
   <rebind input="kb1_np_0"/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_target_nearest_hostile">
   <rebind input="kb1_np_1"/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_target_reticle_focus">
   <rebind input="kb1_np_divide"/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_target_toggle_pinned_focused">
   <rebind input="kb1_np_9"/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_toggle_mouse_aim_only">
   <rebind input="kb1_numlock"/>
  </action>
 </actionmap>
 <actionmap name="spaceship_target_hailing">
  <action name="v_target_hail">
   <rebind input="kb1_lshift+8"/>
  </action>
 </actionmap>
 <actionmap name="spaceship_scanning">
  <action name="v_scanning_trigger_scan">
   <rebind defaultInput="mouse1" input="kb1_lshift+5"/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_toggle_scan_mode">
   <rebind input="kb1_lshift+4"/>
  </action>
 </actionmap>
 <actionmap name="spaceship_ping">
  <action name="v_dec_ping_focus_angle">
   <rebind defaultInput="mwheel_down" input="kb1_lshift+7"/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_inc_ping_focus_angle">
   <rebind defaultInput="mwheel_up" input="kb1_lshift+6"/>
  </action>
 </actionmap>
 <actionmap name="spaceship_mining">
  <action name="v_decrease_mining_throttle">
   <rebind defaultInput="mwheel_down" input="kb1_lshift+q"/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_increase_mining_throttle">
   <rebind defaultInput="mwheel_up" input="kb1_lshift+backspace"/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_toggle_mining_laser_fire">
   <rebind defaultInput="mouse1" input="kb1_lshift+0"/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_toggle_mining_laser_type">
   <rebind defaultInput="mouse2" input="kb1_lshift+equals"/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_toggle_mining_mode">
   <rebind input="kb1_lshift+9"/>
  </action>
 </actionmap>
 <actionmap name="spaceship_turret">
  <action name="v_aim_pitch_down">
   <rebind input="kb1_lshift+t"/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_aim_pitch_up">
   <rebind input="kb1_lshift+r"/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_aim_yaw_left">
   <rebind input="kb1_lshift+w"/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_aim_yaw_right">
   <rebind input="kb1_lshift+e"/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_target_cycle_all_back">
   <rebind input="kb1_lshift+i"/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_target_cycle_all_fwd">
   <rebind input="kb1_lshift+u"/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_target_cycle_friendly_back">
   <rebind input="kb1_lshift+p"/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_target_cycle_friendly_fwd">
   <rebind input="kb1_lshift+o"/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_target_cycle_hostile_back">
   <rebind input="kb1_lshift+a"/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_target_cycle_hostile_fwd">
   <rebind input="kb1_lshift+rbracket"/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_target_cycle_subitem_back">
   <rebind input="kb1_lshift+g"/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_target_cycle_subitem_fwd">
   <rebind input="kb1_lshift+f"/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_target_focus_root_entity">
   <rebind input="kb1_lshift+d"/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_target_nearest_hostile">
   <rebind input="kb1_lshift+s"/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_target_reticle_focus">
   <rebind input="kb1_y"/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_target_toggle_pinned_focused">
   <rebind input="kb1_lshift+lbracket"/>
  </action>
 </actionmap>
 <actionmap name="spaceship_weapons">
  <action name="v_attack1_group1">
   <rebind defaultInput="mouse1" input="kb1_lshift+h"/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_attack1_group2">
   <rebind defaultInput="mouse2" input="kb1_lshift+j"/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_turret_gyromode">
   <rebind input="kb1_lshift+apostrophe"/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_weapon_cycle_aimmode">
   <rebind input="kb1_lshift+semicolon"/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_weapon_cycle_ammo_back">
   <rebind input="kb1_lshift+l"/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_weapon_cycle_ammo_fwd">
   <rebind input="kb1_lshift+k"/>
  </action>
 </actionmap>
 <actionmap name="spaceship_missiles">
  <action name="v_weapon_arm_missile">
   <rebind defaultInput="mouse3" input="kb1_lshift+backslash"/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_weapon_launch_missile">
   <rebind defaultInput="mouse3" input="kb1_lshift+oem_102"/>
  </action>
 </actionmap>
 <actionmap name="spaceship_defensive">
  <action name="v_shield_raise_level_back">
   <rebind input="kb1_lshift+b"/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_shield_raise_level_down">
   <rebind input="kb1_lshift+slash"/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_shield_raise_level_forward">
   <rebind input="kb1_lshift+v"/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_shield_raise_level_left">
   <rebind input="kb1_lshift+m"/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_shield_raise_level_right">
   <rebind input="kb1_lshift+comma"/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_shield_raise_level_up">
   <rebind input="kb1_lshift+period"/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_shield_reset_level">
   <rebind input="kb1_lshift+print"/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_weapon_cycle_countermeasure_back">
   <rebind input="kb1_lshift+c"/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_weapon_cycle_countermeasure_fwd">
   <rebind input="kb1_lshift+x"/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_weapon_launch_countermeasure">
   <rebind input="kb1_lshift+z"/>
  </action>
 </actionmap>
 <actionmap name="spaceship_power">
  <action name="v_power_focus_group_1">
   <rebind input="kb1_lshift+scrolllock"/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_power_focus_group_2">
   <rebind input="kb1_lshift+pause"/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_power_focus_group_3">
   <rebind input="kb1_lshift+insert"/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_power_reset_focus">
   <rebind input="kb1_lshift+home"/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_power_throttle_down">
   <rebind input="kb1_lshift+delete"/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_power_throttle_max">
   <rebind input="kb1_lshift+pgdn"/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_power_throttle_min">
   <rebind input="kb1_lshift+up"/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_power_throttle_up">
   <rebind input="kb1_lshift+pgup"/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_power_toggle">
   <rebind input="kb1_lshift+numlock"/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_power_toggle_group_1">
   <rebind input="kb1_lshift+left"/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_power_toggle_group_2">
   <rebind input="kb1_lshift+down"/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_power_toggle_group_3">
   <rebind input="kb1_lshift+right"/>
  </action>
 </actionmap>
 <actionmap name="spaceship_radar">
  <action name="v_radar_cycle_zoom_fwd">
   <rebind input="kb1_lshift+np_multiply"/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_radar_toggle_active_or_passive">
   <rebind input="kb1_lshift+np_divide"/>
  </action>
 </actionmap>
 <actionmap name="spaceship_hud">
  <action name="mobiglas">
   <rebind input="kb1_lshift+np_subtract"/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_hud_open_scoreboard">
   <rebind input="kb1_lshift+np_7"/>
  </action>
  <action name="v_starmap">
   <rebind input="kb1_lshift+np_8"/>
  </action>
 </actionmap>
 <actionmap name="lights_controller">
  <action name="v_lights">
   <rebind input="kb1_lshift+np_9"/>
  </action>
 </actionmap>
 <actionmap name="player">
  <action name="attack1">
   <rebind defaultInput="mouse1" input="kb1_rshift+2"/>
  </action>
  <action name="combatheal">
   <rebind input="kb1_rshift+x"/>
  </action>
  <action name="crouch">
   <rebind input="kb1_lshift+np_2"/>
  </action>
  <action name="drop">
   <rebind input="kb1_rshift+j"/>
  </action>
  <action name="fixed_speed_decrement">
   <rebind defaultInput="mwheel_down" input="kb1_rshift+oem_102"/>
  </action>
  <action name="fixed_speed_increment">
   <rebind defaultInput="mwheel_up" input="kb1_rshift+backslash"/>
  </action>
  <action name="force_respawn">
   <rebind input="kb1_rshift+slash"/>
  </action>
  <action name="free_thirdperson_camera">
   <rebind input="kb1_rshift+b"/>
  </action>
  <action name="grenade">
   <rebind input="kb1_rshift+equals"/>
  </action>
  <action name="holster">
   <rebind input="kb1_rshift+h"/>
  </action>
  <action name="inspect">
   <rebind input="kb1_rshift+k"/>
  </action>
  <action name="jump">
   <rebind input="kb1_lshift+np_1"/>
  </action>
  <action name="leanleft">
   <rebind input="kb1_lshift+np_period"/>
  </action>
  <action name="leanright">
   <rebind input="kb1_rshift+1"/>
  </action>
  <action name="melee_AttackHeavyLeft">
   <rebind defaultInput="mouse1" input="kb1_rshift+5"/>
  </action>
  <action name="melee_AttackHeavyRight">
   <rebind defaultInput="mouse2" input="kb1_rshift+6"/>
  </action>
  <action name="melee_AttackLightLeft">
   <rebind defaultInput="mouse1" input="kb1_rshift+3"/>
  </action>
  <action name="melee_AttackLightRight">
   <rebind defaultInput="mouse2" input="kb1_rshift+4"/>
  </action>
  <action name="melee_block">
   <rebind defaultInput="mouse1_2" input="kb1_rshift+7"/>
  </action>
  <action name="melee_dodgeBack">
   <rebind input="kb1_rshift+0"/>
  </action>
  <action name="melee_dodgeLeft">
   <rebind input="kb1_rshift+8"/>
  </action>
  <action name="melee_dodgeRight">
   <rebind input="kb1_rshift+9"/>
  </action>
  <action name="mobiglas">
   <rebind input="kb1_rshift+n"/>
  </action>
  <action name="moveback">
   <rebind input="kb1_lshift+np_6"/>
  </action>
  <action name="moveforward">
   <rebind input="kb1_lshift+np_5"/>
  </action>
  <action name="moveleft">
   <rebind input="kb1_lshift+np_add"/>
  </action>
  <action name="moveright">
   <rebind input="kb1_lshift+np_4"/>
  </action>
  <action name="nextweapon">
   <rebind input="kb1_rshift+d"/>
  </action>
  <action name="pl_hud_open_scoreboard">
   <rebind input="kb1_rshift+m"/>
  </action>
  <action name="port_modification_select">
   <rebind defaultInput="mouse1" input="kb1_rshift+comma"/>
  </action>
  <action name="prevweapon">
   <rebind input="kb1_rshift+f"/>
  </action>
  <action name="prone">
   <rebind input="kb1_lshift+np_3"/>
  </action>
  <action name="refillgastank">
   <rebind input="kb1_rshift+c"/>
  </action>
  <action name="reload">
   <rebind input="kb1_rshift+g"/>
  </action>
  <action name="selectMeleeWeapon">
   <rebind input="kb1_rshift+rbracket"/>
  </action>
  <action name="selectUnarmedCombat">
   <rebind input="kb1_rshift+s"/>
  </action>
  <action name="selectUtilityItem">
   <rebind input="kb1_rshift+a"/>
  </action>
  <action name="selectgadget">
   <rebind input="kb1_rshift+lbracket"/>
  </action>

  SOME DELETED FOR DISPLAY PURPOSES

  </action>
  <action name="eva_view_yaw_left">
   <rebind input="kb1_rshift+pause"/>
  </action>
  <action name="eva_view_yaw_right">
   <rebind input="kb1_rshift+insert"/>
  </action>
  <action name="eva_yaw_left">
   <rebind input="kb1_rshift+pgdn"/>
  </action>
  <action name="eva_yaw_right">
   <rebind input="kb1_rshift+up"/>
  </action>
 </actionmap>
 <actionmap name="player_input_optical_tracking">
  <action name="foip_cyclechannel">
   <rebind input="kb1_rshift+np_0"/>
  </action>
  <action name="foip_pushtotalk">
   <rebind input="kb1_rshift+np_1"/>
  </action>
  <action name="foip_pushtotalk_proximity">
   <rebind input="kb1_rshift+np_2"/>
  </action>
  <action name="foip_recalibrate">
   <rebind input="kb1_rshift+np_enter"/>
  </action>
  <action name="foip_viewownplayer">
   <rebind input="kb1_rshift+np_3"/>
  </action>
  <action name="headtrack_enabled">
   <rebind input="kb1_rshift+np_4"/>
  </action>
  <action name="headtrack_hold">
   <rebind input="kb1_rshift+np_5"/>
  </action>
  <action name="headtrack_recalibrate">
   <rebind input="kb1_rshift+np_6"/>
  </action>
 </actionmap>
 <actionmap name="player_choice">
  <action name="pc_interaction_mode">
   <rebind input="kb1_rshift+np_period"/>
  </action>
 </actionmap>
</ActionMaps>
```

I am trying to get the `names` for `action` and the `input` for `rebind` with the following code:

```
// Create XML document
xml_document<> doc;
xml_node<> * root_node;

// Read the xml file into a vector
ifstream theFile (fqn_file);
vector<char> buffer((istreambuf_iterator<char>(theFile)), istreambuf_iterator<char>());
buffer.push_back('\0');

// Parse the buffer using the xml file parsing library into doc
doc.parse<0>(&buffer[0]);

// Find root node
root_node = doc.first_node("ActionMaps");

// Iterate over 'ActionMaps' subtree
for (xml_node<> * actionmap_node = root_node->first_node("actionmap"); actionmap_node; actionmap_node = actionmap_node->next_sibling())
{
    wxLogMessage("I found name subsection %s ",
        actionmap_node->first_attribute("name")->value());

    // Iterate over 'action' subtree
    for(xml_node<> * action_node = actionmap_node->first_node("action"); action_node; action_node = action_node->next_sibling())
    {
        wxLogMessage("I found action name %s ",
            action_node->first_attribute("name")->value());

        // Iterate over 'rebind' subtree
        for(xml_node<> * rebind_node = action_node->first_node("rebind"); rebind_node; rebind_node = rebind_node->next_sibling())
        {
            wxLogMessage("I found key %s ",
                rebind_node->first_attribute("input")->value());
        }
    }
}
```

The code basically works and create the following output:

```
20:19:17: I found name subsection spaceship_general 
20:19:17: I found action name v_toggle_all_doorlocks 
20:19:17: I found key kb1_lshift+l 
20:19:17: I found name subsection spaceship_view 
20:19:17: I found action name v_view_dynamic_focus 
20:19:17: I found key js1_slider1 
20:19:17: I found action name v_view_look_behind 
20:19:17: I found key js1_button8 
20:19:17: I found name subsection spaceship_movement 
20:19:17: I found action name v_accel_range_rel 
20:19:17: I found key js1_rotx 
20:19:17: I found action name v_afterburner 
20:19:17: I found key js1_button30 
20:19:17: I found action name v_autoland 
20:19:17: I found key js1_button14 
20:19:17: I found action name v_brake 
20:19:17: I found key js1_button7 
20:19:17: I found action name v_ifcs_toggle_cruise_control 
20:19:17: I found key js1_button12 
20:19:17: I found action name v_ifcs_toggle_esp 
20:19:17: I found key js1_button11 
20:19:17: I found action name v_ifcs_toggle_gforce_safety 
20:19:17: I found key js1_button10 
20:19:17: I found action name v_ifcs_toggle_speed_limiter 
20:19:17: I found key js1_button9 
20:19:17: I found action name v_ifcs_toggle_vector_decoupling 
20:19:17: I found key js1_button6 
20:19:17: I found action name v_roll 
20:19:17: I found key js1_x 
20:19:17: I found action name v_speed_range_rel 
20:19:17: I found key js1_roty 
20:19:17: I found action name v_strafe_back 
20:19:17: I found key js1_  
20:19:17: I found action name v_strafe_down 
20:19:17: I found key js1_button22 
20:19:17: I found action name v_strafe_forward 
20:19:17: I found key js1_  
20:19:17: I found action name v_strafe_left 
20:19:17: I found key js1_button23 
20:19:17: I found action name v_strafe_longitudinal 
20:19:17: I found key js1_z 
20:19:17: I found action name v_strafe_right 
20:19:17: I found key js1_button21 
20:19:17: I found action name v_strafe_up 
20:19:17: I found key js1_button20 
20:19:17: I found action name v_target_match_vel 
20:19:17: I found key js1_button28 
20:19:17: I found action name v_toggle_landing_system 
20:19:17: I found key js1_button13 
20:19:17: I found action name v_toggle_vtol 
20:19:17: I found key js1_button14 
20:19:17: I found action name v_yaw 
20:19:17: I found key js1_rotz 
20:19:17: I found name subsection spaceship_targeting 
20:19:17: I found action name v_target_cycle_all_back 
20:19:17: I found key js1_hat1_down 
20:19:17: I found action name v_target_cycle_all_fwd 
20:19:17: I found key js1_hat1_up 
20:19:17: I found action name v_target_cycle_friendly_back 
20:19:17: I found key js1_button19 
20:19:17: I found action name v_target_cycle_friendly_fwd 
20:19:17: I found key js1_button17 
20:19:17: I found action name v_target_cycle_hostile_back 
20:19:17: I found key js1_hat1_left 
20:19:17: I found action name v_target_cycle_hostile_fwd 
20:19:17: I found key js1_hat1_right 
20:19:17: I found action name v_target_cycle_subitem_back 
20:19:17: I found key js1_button18 
20:19:17: I found action name v_target_cycle_subitem_fwd 
20:19:17: I found key js1_button16 
20:19:17: I found name subsection spaceship_weapons 
20:19:17: I found action name v_attack1_group2 
20:19:17: I found key js1_button5 
20:19:17: I found name subsection spaceship_missiles 
20:19:17: I found action name v_weapon_arm_missile 
20:19:17: I found key js1_button2 
20:19:17: I found action name v_weapon_launch_missile 
20:19:17: I found key js1_button2 
20:19:17: I found name subsection spaceship_defensive 
20:19:17: I found action name v_weapon_cycle_countermeasure_fwd 
20:19:17: I found key js1_button3 
20:19:17: I found action name v_weapon_launch_countermeasure 
20:19:17: I found key js1_button4
```

But the result is not as expected:

- Random action names in the tree are selected
- The keys does not fit to the previous selected action name but are chosen from somewhere

I do not understand the reason behind it. This is from my perspective a simple recursion.
Anyone who can bring me back onto the right path?

Comment: "I found action name v_view_dynamic_focus " - Your XML doesn't seem to include this action, are you 101% sure that's really the file you're trying to parse???

Comment: Your code isn't recursion, by the way, just iteration.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I had to shorten the XML file due to lenght restrictions (see " SOME DELETED FOR DISPLAY PURPOSES" in the XML file). v_view_dynamic_focus is included in the full file.

I did meanwhile further research. The code processing the XML file works flawless when compiling it without wxWidgets and I get the output I am expecting.

So my current assumption is that the problem has to do with wxThread. wxLogMessage is not the problem as the same happens if I write the lines into a file.

Comment: So I guess there is something happening during the thread processing I actually do not understand I am digging further into it on the next weekend. Yes, you are right. It's iteration, not recursion. Sorry for the mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above code is not the problem and runs flawless when compiling it without wxWidgets. So I am closing this and dig further into wxWidgets direction.